# How to zoom doughnut piece on hover in Chart.js (react-chartjs-2)

Tags: javascript, chart.js, react-chartjs, chartjs-2.6.0

I need to zoom a segment of my doughnut with chart.js (react-chartjs-2). Please see the image for the desired result.

[image: ![]]

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/q367y419mw

Comment: If you wan't help it is best to show what code you already have, and what attempts you already made.

Comment: @Luuklag , sure. Code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/q367y419mw

Comment: please paste your code directly into your question. Links may die over time, making your question obsolete.

Comment: @Wepster I know that's and old question but I have the same problem... Did you resolve it? Can you share it?

Comment: @SantiagoCerroLópez I used d3.js library instead of react-chart-js. The tutorial is here: https://medium.com/localmed-engineering/svg-pie-chart-using-react-and-d3-43a381ce7246